# Blur effect is not working properly in kde neon 13.3

Tags: kde-plasma

I enabled the blur effect according to [how_to_enable_kde_513_blur](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/8r04rv/how_to_enable_kde_513_blur) , and it works.

But when I right clicked on desktop icon, it looks like below:

[image]

The second level menu's blur effect looks right. Any ideas ?

---

> Compositor: OpenGL 3.1
>
> Intel hd 520, modesetting driver
>
> openSUSE Tumbleweed 20180613
>
> Color theme: Breeze dark

---

Thanks to trmdi.

Answer (score 1):

[Bug 395262](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=395262) says a fix was committed for the (future) Plasma 5.14 release.

Comment: When was plasma 5.14 release

Comment: @SandeepPrasadKushwaha, I added a clarification that 5.14 is a future release. You can find release dates via https://community.kde.org/Schedules/Plasma_5